# Flutter - How to integrate Google Maps without map_view

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

Please how can I integrate google maps into my flutter project other than downloading the `map_view` plugin, because it doesn't seem to be working with the new flutter update, and it only uses static maps.

Comment: [Try this fix.](https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/issues/129#issuecomment-436954546)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the official flutter plugin for [Google Maps](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter)

It has a nice example package and is easy to use.